# Repair paddle head and shaft

Tags: epoxy

Looking for some ideas on repairing this standup paddle-board handle/head.

The polymer (I assume) handle has torn right where the head slides in. Visible in the image is the eye where it was seated before. This head never needs to come off so I'm looking for a repair that permanently attached the head.

My current thoughts are water-resistant/compatible epoxy and clamp it while it sets. Other ideas welcome.

[image: broken paddle]

Comment: Would the paddle be equally functional if it were shorter by the length of the broken section? If so, you can cut it just past the break, then glue it permanently.

Comment: Since this is a home-focused stack, I’d suggest migration to The Great Outdoors for an answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Epoxy with an overwrap of fiberglass cloth (or kevlar or carbon if you happen to have some of those kicking around and want to use them) to reinforce it. Merely epoxying that will break again in no time flat.

The epoxy-saturated reinforcement should go approximately as far again up the shaft as the socket is long. That is, it should be twice as long as the socket, or longer.

Alternatively, just get a new handle-shaft, if available from the maker. Or find a generic non-polymer tube the correct size to make a new handle-shaft. That appears to have been a poor choice of material for the job, looking at the way it broke.

Alternative 2, cut the handle-shaft off and have it be one-socket-length **shorter.** Drill a new hole to engage the catch. Pretty much what @MTA suggested. I'll edit this alternative out if @MTA chooses to make that comment an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the mention, but no need to edit. I expected the question to be closed as off-topic, so I left just a comment.